# How to iterate through a list of string tuples of varying lengths in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate through a list of Tuples which are of varying length. However, I'm just trying to figure something out regarding it.

```
test_list = [("rock", "paper", "scissors"),("go","fish"),("uno")]

for each_tuple in test_list:
    for each_word in each_tuple:
       print(each_word)
```

This prints

```
rock
paper
scissors
go
fish
u
n
o
```

What is a solution I could use such that uno is printed as "uno" and not as u n o as separate letters. I understand why this is occuring, but I'm not sure what I should be implementing to "check" whether or not the tuple only has a single element in it vs. multiple.

Answer (score 7):

This is a subtle distinction in Python syntax.  Parentheses serve multiple purposes, most of the ones you'll see fall into one of three categories: (1) expression parentheses, as in changing the precedence order of arithmetic; (2) constructing a tuple; (constructing a generator).

```
test_list = [("rock", "paper", "scissors"),("go","fish"),("uno")]
```

Your first two pairs of parentheses have internal commas: they're obviously tuples.  However, the third is more easily taken as a simple expression, so it evaluates to just the string:

```
test_list = [("rock", "paper", "scissors"),("go","fish"),"uno"]
```

To get what you want, force a one-element tuple with a simple comma:

```
test_list = [("rock", "paper", "scissors"),("go","fish"),("uno", )]
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are not defining a proper tuple. Your iteration is fine.

But you have:

```
test_list = [("rock", "paper", "scissors"),("go","fish"),("uno")]
```

When you should have:

```
test_list = [("rock", "paper", "scissors"),("go","fish"),("uno",)]
```

Note the extra comma. Without it, the parentheses wrapping "uno" are effectively ignored, and "uno" the string becomes the item iterated, which yields individual characters.

This is simply a requirement for specifying single element tuples in Python.

Answer (score 2):

uno is not a tupple in your scenario.
to make it a tuple change it to:

```
test_list = [("rock", "paper", "scissors"),("go","fish"),("uno",)]
```

note the added coma after uno

Answer (score 2):

You got a lot of great answers to your original question.  Separately, you might be interested to know that the `chain` function from the the `itertools` standard library is convenient for the type of iteration you are performing and might be worth considering.

Example:

```
from itertools import chain

test_list = [("rock", "paper", "scissors"),("go","fish"),("uno",)]

for each_word in chain.from_iterable(test_list):
    print(each_word)
```

Output:

```
rock
paper
scissors
go
fish
uno
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the required output just put a coma after "uno", like this.

```
("uno",)
```